# How to change (via custom code) the order in which the columns of a view result are rendered?

Tags: views, theming

I have a table created in a Drupal 7 site, using [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) (version 3). I need to change the columns' order depending on some custom code I have.

I've tried looking into all views' hooks, but I couldn't find anything regarding the order in which the columns will be rendered. Where should I look into?

Comment: [`hook_views_query_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) is probably the best place.

Comment: The only thing I've found there is the $view -> field array. Each entry there has a position property. Nothing changes if I alter it though

Comment: Have you tried altering the query? `$query->orderby[0]['field'] = "field_name ASC";`

Comment: I need to alter the order of the columns in the table, not the results' order.

Comment: Columns not rows, of course, sorry my bad :)